# calculating heading from latitude and longitude in excel

Tags: excel, heading

I would like to calculate heading direction from the north between 2 points with P1(lat1 , long2) and P2(lat2 long2), in excel.

Comment: What exactly is the problem you're having with doing that? A couple of seconds and Google got me this: http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what level of accuracy you are looking for. [Haversine formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula) is simple yet may be insufficient since it assumes Earth surface is a perfect sphere (which it is not) and provides only limited accuracy.
[Vincenty's formulae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vincenty%27s_formulae) provide way better, geodesic grade accuracy (1.46E-6 degrees).
VBA Excel implementation I put together can be found on GitHub: https://github.com/tdjastrzebski/Vincenty-Excel.
`VincentyInvFwdAzimuth()` function should get you what you need.

Answer (score 0):

I have a function used for ham radio calculations. A "pure" formula was too bulky for me.

```
Function BearingFromCoord(lat_base_deg, long_base_deg, lat_dest_deg, long_dest_deg As Single) As Long
   Dim rad_deg_factor As Single
   Dim long_diff As Single
   Dim frac0 As Single
   Dim frac1 As Single
   Dim frac2 As Single
   Dim lat_base As Single
   Dim long_base As Single
   Dim lat_dest As Single
   Dim long_dest As Single
   Dim bearing As Single

   rad_deg_factor = 360 / (2 * pi())

   long_diff = (long_base_deg - long_dest_deg) / rad_deg_factor
     lat_base = lat_base_deg / rad_deg_factor
       lat_dest = lat_dest_deg / rad_deg_factor
          frac0 = Sin(lat_base) * Sin(lat_dest) _
              + Cos(lat_base) * Cos(lat_dest) _
                * Cos(long_diff)
             bearing = rad_deg_factor * Application.WorksheetFunction.Acos((Sin(lat_dest) _
                        - Sin(lat_base) * frac0) _
                    / (Cos(lat_base) * Sin(WorksheetFunction.Acos(frac0))))
          If Sin(long_diff) < 0 Then
            BearingFromCoord = bearing
          Else
            BearingFromCoord = 360 - bearing
          End If
End Function

Private Function pi() As Single
  pi = 3.1415926535
End Function
```